# Failing to save Entity into DB using Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using Spring 3.3.4 with Hibernate 5.1.3, with java 1.7, and Sql Server DB. I wrote a simple class mapped to a Table but can not save it. I get an Exception that my ID is null. I expected it to be autogenerated but that fails. From Exception I can see that it expects to find a sequence. But in previous versions of Hibernate The same could be achieved with native generator without the use of sequences. It should be still possible. Below are my configuration, code and exception:

Configuration file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=webadmin;useCursors=true"/>
        <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="username" value="XXX"/>
        <property name="password" value="YYY"/>
        <property name="initialSize" value="5"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="mySessionFactory" name="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.xxxx.common.model"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

My relevant code fragment:

```
    @Entity(name = "Task")
@Table(name = "task")
public class TaskImpl extends SubmittedTaskImpl implements Task {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1711538547188780401L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long taskId;
```

And finally my exception:

```
    2016-12-14 15:20:58.076 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] ERROR org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure - could not read a hi value
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid object name 'hibernate_sequence'.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2988) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2421) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:671) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.MSCursorResultSet.processOutput(MSCursorResultSet.java:943) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.MSCursorResultSet.cursorCreate(MSCursorResultSet.java:541) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.MSCursorResultSet.<init>(MSCursorResultSet.java:154) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQLQuery(JtdsStatement.java:452) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:1029) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure.executeQuery(TableStructure.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure.access$300(TableStructure.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1$1.execute(TableStructure.java:139) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1$1.execute(TableStructure.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.WorkExecutor.executeReturningWork(WorkExecutor.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractReturningWork.accept(AbstractReturningWork.java:34) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1.getNextValue(TableStructure.java:125) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.NoopOptimizer.generate(NoopOptimizer.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.generate(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:412) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:682) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:674) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:669) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at com.cyberbit.common.repositories.HarvestTaskManagementRepository.saveTask(HarvestTaskManagementRepository.java:23) ~[HarvestTaskManagementRepository.class:?]
    at com.cyberbit.services.HarvestingTaskManagementService.submitTask(HarvestingTaskManagementService.java:47) ~[HarvestingTaskManagementService.class:?]
    at com.cyberbit.services.HarvestingTaskManagementService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$82836951.invoke(<generated>) ~[HarvestingTaskManagementService.class:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at com.cyberbit.services.HarvestingTaskManagementService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$74298c8f.submitTask(<generated>) ~[HarvestingTaskManagementService.class:?]
    at com.cyberbit.controllers.HarvestingTaskManagementController.submitTask(HarvestingTaskManagementController.java:44) ~[HarvestingTaskManagementController.class:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650) ~[servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) ~[servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71) ~[log4j-web-2.7.jar:2.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.63]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [?:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [?:1.7.0_79]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.63]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_79]
2016-12-14 15:20:58.076 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 208, SQLState: S0002
2016-12-14 15:20:58.077 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Invalid object name 'hibernate_sequence'.
2016-12-14 15:20:58.077 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 16945, SQLState: S1000
2016-12-14 15:20:58.077 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - The cursor was not declared.
2016-12-14 15:20:58.077 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 24000
2016-12-14 15:20:58.077 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - The executeQuery method must return a result set.
2016-12-14 15:20:58.105 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] ERROR com.cyberbit.controllers.HarvestingTaskManagementController - An error has occurred
com.cyberbit.common.exceptions.EntityRetrievalFailureDueToInfrastructureException: Error occurred while saving task to DB
    at com.cyberbit.common.repositories.HarvestTaskManagementRepository.saveTask(HarvestTaskManagementRepository.java:25)
    at com.cyberbit.services.HarvestingTaskManagementService.submitTask(HarvestingTaskManagementService.java:47)
    at com.cyberbit.services.HarvestingTaskManagementService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$82836951.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    ...
    at com.cyberbit.services.HarvestingTaskManagementService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$74298c8f.submitTask(<generated>)
    at com.cyberbit.controllers.HarvestingTaskManagementController.submitTask(HarvestingTaskManagementController.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    ...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error performing isolated work
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1.getNextValue(TableStructure.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.NoopOptimizer.generate(NoopOptimizer.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.generate(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:412)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:682)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:674)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:669)
    at com.cyberbit.common.repositories.HarvestTaskManagementRepository.saveTask(HarvestTaskManagementRepository.java:23)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid object name 'hibernate_sequence'.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2988)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2421)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:671)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.MSCursorResultSet.processOutput(MSCursorResultSet.java:943)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.MSCursorResultSet.cursorCreate(MSCursorResultSet.java:541)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.MSCursorResultSet.<init>(MSCursorResultSet.java:154)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQLQuery(JtdsStatement.java:452)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:1029)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure.executeQuery(TableStructure.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure.access$300(TableStructure.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1$1.execute(TableStructure.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1$1.execute(TableStructure.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.WorkExecutor.executeReturningWork(WorkExecutor.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractReturningWork.accept(AbstractReturningWork.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:57)
    ... 65 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > 14:33:10,373 ERROR [org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-3) could not read a hi value:
> >     java.sql.SQLException: invalid object name 'hibernate_sequence'.
>
> the reason is that instead of the IdentityGenerator the
>   SequenceStyleGenerator is used although we are using the correct
>   MSSQLServerDialect and it returns supportsIdentityColumns() = true.
>   The SequenceStyleGenerator tries to find the 'hibernate_sequence'
>   table which does not exist
>   workaround for mssql by changing code to:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public long getId()
{
   return id;
}
```

Check more of this error in here 
[reported issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6881)

Comment: Thanks. Following the link I turned off the property "hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" (set it to "false"). Then it works without changing it to GenerationType.IDENTITY. Also, what I changed was that in my SQL Server I changed the creation of column in the following manner:

Old:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[bot_task](
 [id] [numeric](19, 0) NOT NULL,
         ...

New:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[bot_task](
 [id] [numeric](19, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
         ...

Comment: Also switching to GenerationType.IDENTITY works as well (without switching off property "hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings")